# Content Query, TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti and XSL transformation

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part, taxonomy

I have something like the following in my Taxonomy Term Store:

```
+ [Managed Metadata Service]
  + Earth (Group)
    + Continents (Term Set)
      + Europe (Term)
        - Italy (Term)
        - France (Term)
      + Asia (Term)
        - China (Term)
        - India (Term)
```

I have a managed metadata column in my page layout that accepts multiple values.

I have the following pages that uses this page layout and its metadata value/s:

- Ceramics (China)
- Tiger (China, India)
- Hinduism (India)
- Gondola (Italy)
- Macaron (France)

On a different page (*groupings.aspx*), I have a content query web part.
What I'd like is to have it display 'Asia' values like:

```
[+] China
      Ceramics (link to the Ceramics page)
      Tiger    (link to the Tiger page)
[+] India
      Hinduism (link to the Hinduism page)
      Tiger    (link to the Tiger page)
```

I need help selecting the filters and developing the xsl for the content query.
The expand/collapse on *China* and *India* would be great but not necessary. I can do that one my own. I just don't have a lot of experience with xsl transformation.

---

Cross-posted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192199/sharepoint-content-query-taxonomy-term-store-and-xsl-transformation